# what will be the CALLBACK_URL fir intuit auth1.0?

Tags: python, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

i want to get the details of customers form my  intuit account to my website by using quickbooks and api provided by them. 
i was following this link : [Python- quickbooks](https://github.com/sidecars/python-quickbooks)

what i have done soo far is :

```
def intuit_details(request):
    client = QuickBooks(
        sandbox=True,
        consumer_key=ConsumerKey,
        consumer_secret=ConsumerSecret,
        callback_url="",
        )
    authorize_url = client.get_authorize_url()
    request_token = client.request_token
    request_token_secret = client.request_token_secret
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

I ma stuck at what will be my call back url and does it needed to be a method that i need to define and do the furthur work.
 i have been stuck to it for 4 days. 
When i put localhost in call back url it return me the value/tokens/keys but i guess that is wrong way to do it.

if anyone can point me i right direction or help me understand what i need to do .
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth callback URL is a URL that you create, which receives the OAuth tokens that Intuit provides to you.

Basically, once the user authorizes access via the Intuit-supplied UI, Intuit redirects them back to your callback URL (again, a URL you create and specify) with the OAuth access tokens appended to the end of it as a query string.

You then store the OAuth credentials, and use them in future REST API requests.

Read all about it in the spec:

- https://oauth.net/core/1.0/#auth_step2

And in Intuit's documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0100_essentials/000500_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_within_your_app

Here's a copy/paste of Intuit's documentation on the subject:

> **Handling the response**
>
> The Intuit OAuth service verifies the signature and consumer key sent
>   in the request. If successful, it returns the access token tuple to
>   the oauth_callback parameter that you specified in the request. A
>   successful response to the request contains the following fields:
>
> **Field | Description**
>
> > oauth_token_secret  | The access token secret.
> >
> > oauth_token | The access token.
>
> All response fields are returned as
>   query parameters, as shown below:
>
> > https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect?
> >     oauth_token_secret=[system generated access token secret]&
> >     oauth_token=[system generated access token]
>
> In persistent storage,
>   save the OAuth oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, and realmId,
>   associating them with the user who is currently authorizing access.
>   Your app needs these values for subsequent requests to the Quickbooks
>   API. Be sure to encrypt the access token and access token secret
>   before saving them in persistent storage.